# Labels' titles are not displayed in a proper distance from a ggplot heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the following dataset:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","small","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)
```

And I create a ggplot2 heatmap with:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
g <- melt(Gene_states22, id.vars = c("gene_symbol","panel"))
p1<-ggplot(g, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                     colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
  facet_grid(~panel,switch = "x")+
  labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
  theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                             size = 14, 
                             face = "bold"), 
        axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                  size = 16, 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 5)),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside")
p1
```

Then I convert it to plotly with:

```
ggplotly(p1)%>%
  layout( autosize = F, width = 1350, height = 600,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                     font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                                                 size = 9, 
                                                                                 color = "black")))
```

My problem is that I cannot adapt the distance of the title and the y-axis title properly form the graph. I want the title to be separated a little bit from the praph and not being stuck and the y-axis title to be a little closer in order to be displayed correctly. I use `axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 5))` but with no difference

Comment: Would using `hjust` or `vjust` within the `element_text()` work?

Comment: It does not make any difference

Comment: Just based on my experience try coding the whole thing in plotly if you want it in plotly. I know there is no facet-function in Plotly. But then you have to find a workaround. When I had to do that, I created a much simpler graph than my ggplot-version

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using margin in the `layout` call to plotly? It would depend on what side of the heatmap your labels are, but it would be something like this:

```
gplotly(p1)%>%
  layout(autosize = F, width = 1350, height = 600, 
  hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white", 
                    font = list(family = "sans serif",  size = 9, color = "black")), 
  margin = list(r=100))
```

[Plotly's website](https://plot.ly/r/setting-graph-size/) has more info on using the `margin` argument.

Comment: You have to play around with margin widths to fit whatever size your viewer is. While setting the size equal to the one above, I got `margin = list(l = 200, b = -10, t =-10))` to work.